# Prove $\int_{|x|\ge \delta} gf_n \to 0$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Prove $\int_{|x|\ge \delta} gf_n \to 0$ where $f_n(x) = \frac{n}{\pi(n^2x^2+1)}$ and $g \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$

For each $n$: $\int_\mathbb{R} f_n = 1$. I already showed this by making a trig substitution.

I thought about trying to show

$$\Biggl\lvert \int_{\mathbb{R}} gf_{n} - \int_{-x}^{x} gf_{n} \Biggr\rvert \to 0$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that, for $\delta > 0$,

$$ \left| \int_{|x|\geq\delta} g(x)f_n(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right|
\leq \left(\sup_{|x|\geq\delta}|f_n(x)|\right)\int_{|x|\geq\delta} |g(x)| \,\mathrm{d}x
\leq \frac{n}{\pi(n^2\delta^2+1)}\|g\|_{L^1}, $$

where $\|g\|_{L^1} = \int |g(x)|\,\mathrm{d}x$ is the $L^1$-norm of $g$. Since this bound converges to $0$ as $n\to\infty$, we are done.

Answer (score 0):

If $|x| \geq \delta$ then $$\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{n}{(n^2x^2+1)} \leq \frac{1}{\pi}\frac{n}{(n^2\delta^2+1)} \to 0$$

So  $f_n(x)=g(x)\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{n}{(n^2x^2+1)} 1_{\{|x|\geq \delta\}} \to 0$

And $|f_n(x)| \leq \frac{1}{\pi}\frac{1}{\delta^2}|g(x)|1_{\{|x| \geq \delta\}} \in L^1$

By DCT you have the conclusion.